# Java sorting List

Tags: java, list

I got a List in java. I get values from a SQL query.

```
public void ReloadPages() throws Exception {        
    try (Connection conn = Framework.GetDatabaseManager().GetBone().getConnection()) {
        try (ResultSet set = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM habbo_shop_pages")) {
            while (set.next()) {
                int Id = set.getInt(1);

                Pages.put(Id, new CatalogPage(set));
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Loaded " + Pages.size() + " Catalog Page(s).");
}
```

Then I store it all. In another function, I want to retrieve certain pages from a parentid.

```
public LinkedList<CatalogPage> getSubPages(int parentId) {
    LinkedList<CatalogPage> pages = new LinkedList<>();

    for (CatalogPage page : this.Pages.values()) {
        if (page.getParentId() != parentId) {
            continue;
        }

        pages.add(page);
    }

    return pages;
}
```

How do I order the list? Now id 4 is above in the shop and 1 at the bottom, but I want it ordered by id. ORDER BY in query doesn't work.

Comment: Does `CatalogPage` implement `Comparable` interface?

Answer (score 21):

Have your class implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and provide said sort ordering in [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) method. And to sort, simply use [`Collections#sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29), although be aware that it's an inline sort.

Comment: You could also just create a new Comparator instead of implementing Comparable.

Comment: @dkellycollins Comparator is indeed more flexible. Having a single comparison method is fine for values that can only be compared exactly, but for aggregated values you often need more than one way to compare them.

Answer (score 14):

You want to sort the list in reverse order then try this:

```
Collections.sort(list,Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: I tried using this, now it doesn't display anything in the shop at all.

Answer (score 6):

Like [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15586227/235635) writes, you can let the elements in the list implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. Alternatively the [Collections#sort(List, Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)]) method, which allows you to sort on different keys, can be used. This can for example be used handle sorting on multiple fields of the elements in the list, e.g. implement a Comparator to sort on date and a different Comparator for sorting on id.

For more info look at the javadoc for the [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface.

### Example

**Code:**

```
package com.stackoverflow.questions;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Question15586200 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Add test data
        LinkedList<CatalogPage> catalogs = new LinkedList<CatalogPage>();
        catalogs.add(new CatalogPage("foo 4", 4));
        catalogs.add(new CatalogPage("bar 1", 1));
        catalogs.add(new CatalogPage("foobar 2", 2));
        catalogs.add(new CatalogPage("barfoo 3", 3));

        // Sort by id
        Collections.sort(catalogs, new Comparator<CatalogPage>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(CatalogPage o1, CatalogPage o2) {
                return Integer.compare(o1.getId(), o2.getId());
            }
        });

        // Print result
        for (CatalogPage page : catalogs) {
            System.err.println(page);
        }
    }

    public static class CatalogPage {
        private String name;
        private int id;

        public CatalogPage(String name, int id) {
            this.name = name;
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "CatalogPage [name=" + name + ", id=" + id + "]";
        }
    }
}
```

**Ouput:**

```
CatalogPage [name=bar 1, id=1]
CatalogPage [name=foobar 2, id=2]
CatalogPage [name=barfoo 3, id=3]
CatalogPage [name=foo 4, id=4]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using **Lambda expressions**, added in Java version 8.

```
Comparator<ProductColor> byProductColorName = (color1, color2) -> Integer.compare(
    color1.getId(), color2.getId());

myProductColorList.stream().sorted(byProductColorName)
    .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));
```

Also i found [this post](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/007-sort-arraylist-stream-of-objects-in-java8/) very usefull.

Comment: I would favor `Comparator<ProductColor> byProductColorName = Comparator.comparingInt(ProductColor::getId);`.

Answer (score 1):

List maintains insertion order. If you want to order in by ID, then use TreeSet and write a external Comparator, by implementing a compare() method of Comparator interface and pass it to the TreeSet constructor. Values will be sorted and ordered by ID.