# Java - Error Collections.sort on Netbeans

Tags: java, arraylist, netbeans

I'm running on Netbeans 8.0.2 and I don't know I can't use the Collections.sort(), I have this error.

```
The type of Sort(Comparator<? super E> is erroneous where E is a type-variable : E extends object declared in class ArrayList
```

Example of code :

```
private void chargeData(String fileName) {
    base.ArticleDao.listeArticles = base.ArticleDao.getListeArticles(fileName);
    base.ArticleDao.listeArticles.sort(null);
    //Collections.sort(listeArticles);
    for (int i = 0; i < base.ArticleDao.listeArticles.size(); i++) {
        lstArticles.add(base.ArticleDao.listeArticles.get(i).toString());
    }
}//chargeData
```

I'm using Collections.sort() in order to.... sort my arrayList but I have this error, even I do :

myArrayList.sort(null) in order to use compareTo().

Do you have some ideas for the configuration on netbeans ? I tested on my school computer, and it was worked.

Thank you for taking time on my problem and have a nice day full of code =)

Comment: `Collections.sort(myArrayList);` is not the same as `myArrayList.sort();`.

Comment: What's the code? Most likely it's an error in the code, as Netbeans itself is just an IDE.

Comment: Is an ArrayList not a collection ? I tested those two ways and the sort worked.

Comment: @Paul Here is a little part of my code =)

Comment: @Arkhall I meant the code where you call `Collections.sort()`.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sorry : base is the package. ArticleDao is where I work on my .txt via a StringTokenizer and listeArticles is my ArrayList.

Comment: @Paul I imported the package java.util.Collections only for using the sort() method on my ArrayList. Edit : Ahhhhhhhhhh I will edit it xD It's okay now =)

Comment: @Arkhall well, in that case, `Collections.sort` and `ArrayList.sort` are two totally different methods. You need to provide a comparator of the appropriate type to [`ArrayList.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-). You should read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/algorithms/index.html#sorting).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java sorting List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586200/java-sorting-list)